# Selenium 2.53.1 so slow

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium tests with IE using `IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1` in a `Windows 7` `64-bit Operating system` `IE 11.0.9`

```
mvn clean test -Denv=iotApp -DsuiteXmlFile=smoke.xml -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\webdrivers\IEDriverServer.exe -Dtest.driver.type=ie
```

but it is extremelly slow !

Is it normal ?

Comment: so, what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You are using `64-bit` IEdriverserver, I would suggest, you should replace it with `32-bit` of IEdriverserver because **64-bit of IEdriverserver is very very slow for the execution.**

*IE driver to determine the root cause. When you are running IE 10 or higher on a 64-bit
version of Windows, by default the process which hosts the containing window that includes
the browser chrome (address bar, navigation buttons, menus, etc.) is a 64-bit process.
The process which hosts the window where content is actually rendered (within each
tab) is a 32-bit process.*

*Some notes. Careful readers will have already realized that this means that even when
you are running 64-bit Windows, you're likely using a 32-bit version of IE to render
the content. This is a powerful argument for continuing to use the 32-bit version of
the IE driver for IE 10 and above: you're not actually running against a 64-bit version
of IE.*

If you insist that you must run the 64-bit version of IEDriverServer.exe,  you can disable native events by setting the `nativeEvents`
capability to false using whatever mechanism your language binding provides for this.

Comment: 10 times faster now :-)